# Command line SFTP "Local to local copy not supported" error

Tags: c#, command-line, sftp

I'm running a program written in C# from the command line as administrator that should generate the batch file (which it does), and then it should sFTP the file to a remote site. I have verified the username and password are correct. When I run the utility (C# program) to do this it says it's transferring the file and then immediately gives me this

> ERROR:  Local to local copy not supported.

However, I can manually (through Filezilla) move the file from our server to their site.  It's probably something silly, but I just can't seem to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated!

There are many files to this program, but here is where the most of the FTP stuff is in the code.  I hope it helps:

```
if (pars.ContainsKey("ftp"))
            {
                var env = (pars.ContainsKey("ftp") ? pars["ftp"] : null) ?? "default";
                entities = entities ?? new SBLStagingEntities();
                settings = settings ?? new SettingReader(entities, env).GetSetting();
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(pars["path"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Transfering {0} using sFTP ................................\t\t", filename);
                var processors = new SblFtpTransport(settings);
                processors.ProcessFile(pars["path"]);
                Console.Write("sFTP Done\n");
            }
```

///-----------------------a different class that is called from the first one------///

```
public SblFtpTransport(Settings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// this method is called by file watcher for each new file dropped in the watched folder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file"></param>
    public void ProcessFile(string file)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);            
        if (!File.Exists(file) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("file does not exist");
            return;
        }
        //ftp the file and record the result in db
        var result = FtpFile(file);

        Log(fileName, result);

        Console.Write("{0}", result);

        Archive(result, file);
    }
```

///-------------------------------another class that is used--------------///

```
public class WatcherSettings
{
    public IFileProcessor CreateProcessor()
    {
        return new SblFtpTransport(new Settings()
                                       {
                                           AchiveFolder = @"C:\Docs\place\Watcher\Archived",
                                           FtpPort = "22",
                                           FtpServer = "xxxxx.someplace.net",
                                           FtpTargetPath = "/StudentBatchLoad_FW",
                                           FtpUsername = "xxx",
                                           Password = "xxxxxxx",


                                       });
    }

    public string WatcherPath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show some code or there isn't much we can do.

Comment: I don't see anything here that generates a batch file, no way to guess what commands are you outputting there, just some random snippets of discombobulated code

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you never call `CreateProcessor()`. And it appears you need to call that so the settings get created properly with the remote host, and that's why you get an error that you're trying to copy to local host. So change your code to call that.

But your code is extremely disjointed and hard to read. Spend some time cleaning it, and step through it with a debugger to see exactly what's happening.